# Converting pcm to .wav - noisy

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

I have been trying to add some code to my application to convert my recorded pcm files to .wav files.
I have got the code to write the header, but for some reason when i play the converted .wav file through a audio player, all you can hear is noise.

This is the code for my converting method:

```
public void writeWavHeader(){
    try {
        File pcmFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TimeShiftRecorder" + File.separator + "Recording.pcm");
        File wavFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TimeShiftRecorder" + File.separator + "Recording_test.wav");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(wavFile);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pcmFile);
        InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        short mBitsPerSample = 16;
        long audioLength = fis.getChannel().size();
        long byteRate = sampleRate * bitsPerSample/8 * channels;
        short format = 1;
        long totalDataLen = audioLength + 36;
        long longSampleRate = 44100;
        byte byteBitsPerSample = (byte) bitsPerSample; // = 16
        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (bitsPerSample/8*channels);  // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = byteBitsPerSample;  // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (audioLength & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((audioLength >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((audioLength >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((audioLength >> 24) & 0xff);
        out.write(header, 0, 44);


        while (dis.available() > 0) {
            out.write(dis.read());
        }
        dis.close();
        out.close();
        //testHeader();

    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.v("recordService", "IOException");
    }

}
```

From all the examples i can find on the web, this header should be correct.

If someone could please help me with where i have gone wrong, i would be immensely grateful.

Thanks
Corey :)

Comment: Try reading the .wav file with something that can interpret raw PCM data in your source format - what should happen is that you get a brief noise as it misinterprets your header as audio, and then plays the following audio correctly.  If not, you have a problem with the data, how you copied it, or somehow got it starting at an odd rather than even offset.  But if playing it as raw audio does work, then you probably have a problem with the header.

Comment: Are you sure the PCM file is little-endian?

Answer (score 0):

Typically WAV format stores each sample with 16 bits of information (across two bytes of memory).  Assure you read the PCM and write to WAV with this in mind.  A single byte can only handle 256 different values per sample (taken 44100 times per second typically) which would make an 8 bit format of low fidelity.  Instead, with 16 bits of storage you then have 2^16 possible different values which is enough for CD quality audio.  When writing such code its handy to have two programs :  (1) convert PCM into WAV and the other (2) to convert WAV back into PCM.  This way you can use (2) to read a known good WAV into PCM as source data to then use (1) to output WAV then compare both WAV for equality.

Also assure you read/write to binary files not normal file mode.

In your case, since WAV format is simply PCM data with a header attached to the front of the file, if you read your PCM as a binary file, output the header to the new WAV file then write your memory buffer as binary to the WAV you should be well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working example.

See: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ for more info

```
/**
 * overload using AudioFormat
 *
 * @param input  raw PCM data
 *               limit of file size for wave file: < 2^(2*4) - 36 bytes (~4GB)
 * @param output file to encode to in wav format
 * @param format corresponding audioformat for PCM data
 * @throws IOException in event of an error between input/output files
 * @see <a href="http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/">soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat</a>
 */
static public void PCMToWAV(File input, File output, AudioFormat format) throws IOException {
    int bitsPerSample;
    switch (format.getEncoding()) {
        case AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT:
            bitsPerSample = 8;
            break;
        case AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT:
            bitsPerSample = 32;
            break;
        case AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT:
        default:
            bitsPerSample = 16;

    }
    PCMToWAV(input, output, format.getChannelCount(), format.getSampleRate(), bitsPerSample);
}

/**
 * @param input         raw PCM data
 *                      limit of file size for wave file: < 2^(2*4) - 36 bytes (~4GB)
 * @param output        file to encode to in wav format
 * @param channelCount  number of channels: 1 for mono, 2 for stereo, etc.
 * @param sampleRate    sample rate of PCM audio
 * @param bitsPerSample bits per sample, i.e. 16 for PCM16
 * @throws IOException in event of an error between input/output files
 * @see <a href="http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/">soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat</a>
 */
static public void PCMToWAV(File input, File output, int channelCount, int sampleRate, int bitsPerSample) throws IOException {
    final int inputSize = (int) input.length();

    try (OutputStream encoded = new FileOutputStream(output)) {
        // WAVE RIFF header
        writeToOutput(encoded, "RIFF"); // chunk id
        writeToOutput(encoded, 36 + inputSize); // chunk size
        writeToOutput(encoded, "WAVE"); // format

        // SUB CHUNK 1 (FORMAT)
        writeToOutput(encoded, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
        writeToOutput(encoded, 16); // subchunk 1 size
        writeToOutput(encoded, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
        writeToOutput(encoded, (short) channelCount); // number of channelCount
        writeToOutput(encoded, sampleRate); // sample rate
        writeToOutput(encoded, sampleRate * channelCount * bitsPerSample / 8); // byte rate
        writeToOutput(encoded, (short) (channelCount * bitsPerSample / 8)); // block align
        writeToOutput(encoded, (short) bitsPerSample); // bits per sample

        // SUB CHUNK 2 (AUDIO DATA)
        writeToOutput(encoded, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
        writeToOutput(encoded, inputSize); // subchunk 2 size
        copy(new FileInputStream(input), encoded);
    }
}


/**
 * Size of buffer used for transfer, by default
 */
private static final int TRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE = 10 * 1024;

/**
 * Writes string in big endian form to an output stream
 *
 * @param output stream
 * @param data   string
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void writeToOutput(OutputStream output, String data) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
        output.write(data.charAt(i));
}

public static void writeToOutput(OutputStream output, int data) throws IOException {
    output.write(data >> 0);
    output.write(data >> 8);
    output.write(data >> 16);
    output.write(data >> 24);
}

public static void writeToOutput(OutputStream output, short data) throws IOException {
    output.write(data >> 0);
    output.write(data >> 8);
}

public static long copy(InputStream source, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    return copy(source, output, TRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE);
}

public static long copy(InputStream source, OutputStream output, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    long read = 0L;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    for (int n; (n = source.read(buffer)) != -1; read += n) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    return read;
}
```